# JDBC tomcat connection pool is not working

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, netbeans

**Apache tomcat log**

> Jul 19, 2014 9:31:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [FrontController] in
>   context with path [/GroupFound] threw exception
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource    at
>   models.bean.Customer.act(Customer.java:32)    at
>   controller.FrontController.processRequest(FrontController.java:40)    at
>   controller.FrontController.doGet(FrontController.java:61)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

**Error**

> org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC
>   driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
>     at models.bean.Customer.act(Customer.java:33)   at
>   controller.FrontController.processRequest(FrontController.java:40)    at
>   controller.FrontController.doGet(FrontController.java:61)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:507)     at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:476)    at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:307)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:253)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
>     ... 26 more

**context.xml**
changed from META-INF folder.  catalina-home/conf/Catalina/localhost/[projectname].xml also have been changed while changing META-INF copy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/GroupFound">
    <Resource auth="Container" 
              defaultReadOnly="false" 
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional" 
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
              initialSize="0" 
              jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer" 
              jmxEnabled="true" 
              logAbandoned="true" 
              maxActive="300" maxIdle="50"
              maxWait="10000" 
              minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="300000"
              minIdle="30" 
              name="jdbc/testcp"
              password="" 
              removeAbandoned="true"
              removeAbandonedTimeout="60" 
              testOnBorrow="true"
              testOnReturn="false" 
              testWhileIdle="true" 
              timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" 
              username="root"
              validationInterval="30000" 
              validationQuery="SELECT 1"/>
</Context>
```

**Web.xml**
changed from application context (netbeans IDE)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FrontController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controller.FrontController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FrontController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>/jdbc/testcp</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

Have been trying to fix it from hours. Searched google and similar issues with no success. I am exhausted. How to fix it? I just want to see DataSource working.

**Details**
JDK 6.1
netbeans 7.2
tomcat 7.0.27

Answer (score 0):

**This appears to be the best guide that I can find:**

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

**A quick test would be to put it here:**

$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml

Comment: How to check if it is getting located or not?

Comment: Find the extracted tomcat server.  Locate your extracted tomcat server you will see a directory called something like apache-tomcat-7.0.54 under that directory you should see a conf folder.  Put your context.xml in that folder, or edit the one that is already there.

Comment: the location you are talking about is showing as catalina_home in netbeans>server>tomcat>properties, which has context.xml with above configuration.

catalina_base is showing other location where there is no config.xml

I am confused!